# Imagemagick convert opaque pixels to specific color

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, pixel

I would like to batch convert a bundle of `PNG files` using `ImageMagick` in aim to change `all opaque pixels` in each image to `specific hexa color`.

I tried

```
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" -colorspace Gray -auto-level "${file%%.png}_gray.png"; done
```

result of just one image converted where all opaque pixels converted to white

I tried without batching , each command successfully done but always wite pixels.

How could I do to set opaque pixels to `#AAA` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `opaque` pixels, I am not sure if you mean pixels with 100% opacity or pixels with non-zero transparency.

**Method 1**

So, if we start with this image which is a blue square with a transparent surround and a further blue surround:

[image]

Then we can make the non-transparent pixels yellow with:

```
convert image.png -fill yellow -colorize 100% result.png
```

[image]

You would use '#AAA' in place of yellow.

**Method 2**

Another way of thinking about it is to set each RGB pixel to 10/16, i.e. A on a hex scale:

```
convert image.png -channel RGB -fx '10/16' result.png
```

[image]

**Method 3**

Or you may have mean that if you start with this - which is a gradient from transparent at the top to black with a red border:

[image]

then you want all except the fully transparent pixels (near the top) to become #AAA (shown here with yellow instead):

```
convert start.png -channel A -threshold 1 -channel RGB -fill yellow -colorize 100% result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer my aim is to transform some icon PNG files to an disabled state (that's why the gray color) so I think your answer is perfect because I would like to let full transparency pixels transparents and other to #AAA color !

Comment: I Used `convert image.png -fill '#AAA' -colorize 100% inactive/image_inactive.png` to do what I needed , thanks ;)